A tcolorbox does not obey fixed minipage height
I’m trying to put a tcbraster from tcolorbox inside a minipage with a fixed height. But clearly, the content inside the tcolorbox does not stretch its glue to fit into that fixed height. Can this be fixed?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t][10\baselineskip][t]{.5\paperwidth}
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1]
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Hello
            
            \vskip 10\baselineskip
                plus 8\baselineskip
                minus 8\baselineskip
            
            World
        \end{tcolorbox}
        
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Hello World
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}



Just a try, use \begin{tcolorbox}[height=11\baselineskip] instead of \begin{tcolorbox}
